# Entity Framework Linq query for filtering records

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am populating a grid. I have two filters for 'MerchantName' and 'MerchantId' columns on screen. If filters are empty and search button is pressed then all record should be displayed otherwise if any of the filter has value the record should be filtered on that. I am using entity framework for pulling data.

```
merchantsList = dbContext.MERCHANT.Where();
```

This is my Entity how can I do it in where clause. MerchantName is string type and merchant Id is Int.

Answer (score 2):

Replace INPUT_MERCHANTNAME and INPUT_ID with request values.

```
var merchantName = INPUT_MERCHANTNAME;
int? id = INPUT_ID;

merchantsList = dbContext.MERCHANT.Where(x =>
  (id.HasValue ? x.Id == id.Value : true) ||
  (!(merchantName == null || merchantName  == "") ? x.MerchantName.Equals(merchantName) : true));
```

This will give you all records if both id and merchantName is null/empty and if they are specified it will filter.

Comment: its giving error : "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsNullOrWhiteSpace(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: While this would work, I wouldn't recommend it, as it's barely readable. Better use a simple if/else. And btw, @Rikard, you've missed an '=' when checking the id.

Answer (score 1):

Seperate your filters.
It will make it much more readable and it will allow you to easily add more filters at a later time.

```
var merchantName = INPUT_MERCHANTNAME;
int? id = INPUT_ID;

var list = dbContext.MERCHANT.AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(merchantName)) {
    list = list.Where(m => m.MerchantName == merchantName);
}

if (id.HasValue) {
    list = list.Where(m => m.Id == id.Value);
}

return list.ToList();
```

EDIT: This will AND the filters together.
If you only want to use one filter at a time, try this:

```
var merchantName = INPUT_MERCHANTNAME;
int? id = INPUT_ID;

var list = dbContext.MERCHANT.AsQueryable();

//Lets say ID is more important than name.
if (id.HasValue) {
    list = list.Where(m => m.Id == id.Value);
}else {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(merchantName)) {
        list = list.Where(m => m.MerchantName == merchantName);
    }
}

return list.ToList();
```

If you want to OR both filters:

```
var merchantName = INPUT_MERCHANTNAME;
int? id = INPUT_ID;

var list = dbContext.MERCHANT.AsQueryable();

list = list.Where(m => (merchantName != null && m.MerchantName == merchantName) || (id != null && m.Id == id.Value));


return list.ToList();
```

Comment: It's not the same as have it in one query. Now you have AND between all filters, how to support OR?

Comment: True, it will AND those filters together. I'll edit the answer

Comment: I do not understand why this has been downvoted. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(textBox.Text == "")
{
  merchantsList = dbContext.MERCHANT.ToList();
}
else
{
  merchantsList = (context.CITY.Where(q => q.MerchantName.Contains(textBox.Text))).ToList();

}
```

I am using this technique for search.